# Copy certain files from specified subdirectories into a separate subdirectory

Tags: shell-script, directory, cp

I want to copy all .fastq files from every subdirectory that ends in '_CSF' into another already created subdirectory, dir1_CSF.

I understand how to copy certain files but not from certain directories.

New to shell scripting, it would be great for some assistance.

Comment: Is this a python-specific question? That is, do you want the answer only in python?

Comment: That was a flub. Edited it

Answer (score 2):

Using shell, you can do it like this:

```
find *_CSF -type f -iname "*.fastq" -exec cp {} dir1_CSF/ \;
```

Comment: This moves all files from the subdirectories with _CSF. How do I limit it to just .fastq files?

Comment: @AgnesCaren Sorry I missed that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set DIR to be the top-level directory and TARGET is your destination directory. Then run:

```
find $DIR \( -type d -name "$TARGET" -prune \) -o \
\( -type f -name "*.fastq" -exec cp -t "$TARGET" {}  + \)
```

Yep, that's the command. This is assuming GNU find and GNU fileutils such as `cp` which provides the handy `-t` parameter for these cases.

#### How it works

The `find` command starts with `$DIR` (whatever yous set it to), finds all files matching your extension (but excluding anything below your `$TARGET` directory). It then passes all those filenames to the `cp` program.